# CSharp to FSharp: Byte array using hex

Tags: f#

I am looking at the following C# code:

```
static readonly byte[] OnFrame = { 0x01 };
static readonly byte[] OffFrame = { 0x02 };
```

Can someone tell me how that would be written in FSharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F# you (almost) don't need to specify types (unless you want to), and values are by default immutable (i.e. you don't need to specify `readonly` either). Array declaration is denoted using the pipe-bracket syntax `[|  |]`.

Whether or not you need explicit `static` depends on where you're declaring this: if you need this as part of a class, you'll have to do `static member`, otherwise you can just do `let`. And I would strongly urge you to ask yourself: do you really need it as part of a class?

All above said, this would be the code:

```
let OnFrame = [| 0x01uy |]
let OffFrame = [| 0x02uy |]
```

(the `uy` part means "unsigned byte"; without it the values will be `int`)

I would also strongly urge you to consider if you really need an array or a list would suffice, but I can't tell definitively without knowing broader context.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you'd specify any other [array in F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx): using `[| |]` syntax.

`byte` literals use `uy` postfix, and hexadecimal literals use `0x` prefix:

```
let onFrame = [| 0x01uy |]
let offFrame = [| 0x02uy |]
```

You can see more on MSDN: [Literals (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233193(v=vs.100).aspx).